# What part of speech is "remaining alive"?

Tags: meaning

Is remaining alive well structured in the following sentence? What does it exactly mean? Is remaining in this case a verb or an adjective?

**Example sentence:** 
But naturally we do not take that into account, any more that we take into account that dinner, and the next day again, dinner, is the condition of our remaining alive.

My sincere apologies if my english makes you cringe, but im jolly desperate.

Comment: What's the full sentence?

Comment: But naturally we do not take that into account, any more that we take into account that dinner, and the next day again, dinner, is the condition of our remaining alive.

Comment: Thanks and can you find a real example? If what you Posted is a real example, your sources are letting you down quite badly.

Ignoring the rest, "… the condition of our remaining alive…" just doesn't work.

"… a condition…" could work but please, can you find a real example?

Alternatively, why not Ask somewhere such as English Language Learners?

Comment: No, the definite article is OK, if it means **THE** condition par excellence for staying alive. Which it does in this case. _Our remaining alive_ is a `POSS`-_ing_ gerund clause, the object of the preposition _of_; _our_ is the subject, _remaining_ is the verb, and _alive_ is the resultative adjective complement of _remain_.

Comment: The sentence is correct, and *remaining alive* is a gerund phrase. The gerund phrase functions as a noun. Swap in an ordinary **noun** to see: *Dinner is the condition of our **happiness**.*

Comment: "Remaining" is a verb functioning as head of the verb phrase "remaining alive". The latter is predicate of the gerund-participial clause "our remaining alive", functioning as complement of the prep "of". "Our" is the subject of the clause and "alive" a subjective predicative complement of "remaining".